# JQuery Slider Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, whmcs

I am looking to create a JQuery Slider Bar that will work with WHMCS Custom Hosting.

WHMCS Configurable Package: http://www.whmcs.com/configurableaddon.php
Slider Example: http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting/

I want to have multiple sliders that the client can choose what they wish to have. The total is calculated as they select the 'slider options'. Once they are finished setting up the Custom package the total is then carried over to the WHMCS software and done as needed.

So, I am trying to get Textfield to Slider. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out the slider plugin on jQuery-ui (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)?

Comment: Yes. I have been looking at it, and reading. Just have not had the full time to devote to play around and learn it. Hoping to do so soon. Just the Textfield to Slider portion.